# Differential graded Lie algebra over an ordinary Lie algebra

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, lie-algebras, differential-graded-algebras

Given a dg (differential graded) Lie algebra $L$ and an ordinary Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$,
is there written somewhere a formal definition of $L$ as a dg Lie algebra over $\mathfrak{g}$?

Comment: Is a dg Lie algebra a [differential graded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_graded_algebra) Lie algebra?

Comment: Given a manifold $M$, by "a manifold over $M$" we mean a manifold $P$ with a map $\pi:P\rightarrow M$. If we want $P$ to have an extra structure, say a Lie group action $P\times G\rightarrow P$, by "a map from $P$ to $M$", it is not reasonable to take any smooth map $\pi:P\rightarrow M$, but to take maps $\pi:P\rightarrow M$ that are $G$-invariant,  $\pi(p.g)=\pi(p)$.. Similarly, I think by "a $dg$-algebra over $\mathfrak{g}$", it should be a $dg$-algebra $(L,d:L\rightarrow L)$ with a morphism of Lie algebras $f:L\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$ such that $f\circ d=f:L\rightarrow \mathfrak{g}$..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik, since a [differential graded Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_graded_Lie_algebra) (I messed up my Wiki link [above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343669/differential-graded-lie-algebra-over-an-ordinary-lie-algebra#comment859280_343669); that's where it should have pointed) is not actually a Lie algebra, what does "a morphism of Lie algebras $f : L \to \mathfrak g$" mean?

Comment: @LSpice :D I thought differential graded Lie algebra is a differential graded algebra with a Lie algebra structure... It is much more complicated than that...  I will leave my comment as it is hoping some one can correct my idea... :)